# UILabel don't show all text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to create an iOS application that would be a quiz but I have a problem with the display. Here is what happens by testing:

**Example of one question of the quiz**

[image: Example of one question of the quiz]

But the question is not displayed entirely. The question is : "En France, depuis les débuts de la Ve République, combien y a-t-il eu de présidents différents élus ?"

I show you the UILabel infos :

[image: UILabel informations]

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot for your help :) !

Comment: You should show your constraints. You probably have a height constraint or a top + bottom constraint. Remove height if you have it. If it's top + bot, remove either one of them.

Comment: __a)__ make the label bigger; __b)__ make the font smaller.

Comment: It's good I find the solution but I have an other problem : It's pretty much the same thing but with a stackView. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the code below.

```
// Swift
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 

// For Swift >= 3
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping // notice the 'b' instead of 'B'
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0

// Objective-C
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

// C# (Xamarin.iOS)
textLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
textLabel.Lines = 0;
```

Comment: numberOfLines is 3. So it should atleast show 3 lines.

Comment: if this property is set to 3, the sizeToFit() method resizes the receiver so that it is big enough to display three lines of text. Refer this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines

Comment: Not if the label is not big enough.

Answer (score 0):

For your text inside the label to wrap , plus adding top && centerX constraints , you need to add a width constraint , so either

> top , centerX , width

**OR**

> top , leading , trailing

Also you may set bottom of it to any component that below it

Answer (score 0):

On the attributes inspector you can just updates the `lines` property to be 0. In this way you won't have to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using autolayout in storybaord you can just remove width from constariants and when you will provide text in it will automatically adjust its width and your label will show all data  or you can set minimum font size in storyboard then it will automatically font will set according to your label width and will show complete label data your just need to pass minimum font size.